# Adding a namespace to a particular node using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have an XML and a section of the XML looks like below

```
<ts:mynode1>
   <ts:systemId>XXX</ts:systemId>
   <ts:sequenceId>YYY</ts:sequenceId>
<ts:/mynode1>
<mynode2>
   <systemId>ZZZ</systemId>
   <sequenceId>AAA</sequenceId>
</mynode1>
```

My objective is to add namespace ts to those nodes which does not have a nodes which does not have a nodespace

is there a way of accomplishing it in C#?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily enough using the objects in System.Xml.Linq; in particular, **XElement** and **XName**.  To give a completely definitive answer I would need to see the rest of your XML (in particular, whatever namespace ts resolves to when it's fully resolved, or the xmlns:ts='http://your/namespace/here' specified earlier in the document.)  However, if ts did resolve to the example used above (**http://your/namespace/here**), you could use the following code to set the ts namespace on every node in the document, assuming "xml" contains the documents XML.

```
function addNamespaces(string xml){
    var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml);
    foreach(var el in doc.Descendants())
        el.Name = "{http://your/namespace/here}" + el.Name.LocalName;
    return doc.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi Sean Thanks for the info. Yes. ts is resolved. I will follow your code